# How to use conditional formatting in Google Sheets to highlight row based on value in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets document where I have cells A1:Z1. In AA1, I have a value total. If that value is greater than 5, I would like A1:Z1 to be highlighted in red. I then want to do this for every row down the sheet. Could somebody help be out with this? I tried using other answers here, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean with `AA1`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all take a look at [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413).

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Select the cells you want to apply format rules to `(A1:Z1)`.
3. Click **Format** and then **Conditional formatting**. A toolbar will open to the right.
4. Under the "Format cells if" drop-down menu, click **Custom formula is**. If there's already a rule, click it or **Add new rule > and then Custom formula is**.
5. On custom formula put this `=SUM(A1:Z1) > 5`
6. Choose other formatting properties.
7. Click **Done**.

The result will be this.
[image]